# Access database from different network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, express

I am trying to build a react-native application and to do so, I am following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB97yPrFwo5hMR8znwt0NqgmmqzoPemnT

My application is like a form. People must enter some data into some fields and they will be sent into a database. People can later see their form from the application. So it is like simple a CRUD todo list application.

However, I do not want to use on-demand cloud computing platforms (AWS, GCP, OVH, ...) to store my data. I have my own server at home (NUC Intel) and want to use it as the application's server (store the data in there).

On my server I want to have a mongodb database and make it available from any computers that request it with the correct credentials. I would add firewalls as well for security.
This way, the react native application will be able to access read and write from this database wherever they are in the world as long as they have internet available.

As my backend I will use nodejs and express.
As my front end React Native and Redux.

Any ideas or tutorials I could follow ? I have been looking a lot but all the tutorials end by storing their database in GCP or AWS ... So is it possible to access mongodb database from a different network? Or would MySQL be a better solution?

Comment: Any specific reason as to why you have a local server to host the DB? It just seems like an outdated approach with all the cloud platforms available.  I know you said you didnt want to use one but Firebase is pretty cool for working with projects like this.  It's free up to a certain point, little setup and easy to use.  If you have 1,000+ users signing up to your application you can then upgrade if need so but Firebase just seems like a good idea here.

Comment: To answer you initial question - this could be of some help;
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-my-local-computer-into-a-server-and-store-databases-in-my-computer-when-I-create-them-using-MySQL